Crawling Ads location, audience size, conversion, action destination breaking by Facebook Marketing API (Insights)
Facebook Marketing API (Insights)
Hello everyone,
I am currently running Meta Ads and have a plan to get data from Meta Marketing API (Insight) (link to this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/).
However, We can't find solution to get some types of data including:

device platform by ad id level (which displays type of device like desktop or mobile when users viewed or clicked Ads).

performance of Ads broke down by location

audience size by ad id level

action destination by ad id level (the destination where ads is directed to, which can be Website or App; or can be returned in the format of link direction )


Do you have any experience in solving this problem, can you help me with this
Thank you and best regards
